# Django previous MySQL raw query still running after changes the database to PostgreSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, django, postgresql

I am facing a problem after replacing the database connection from MySQL to PostgreSQL. Everything works fine but the MySQL raw query still running while I change it to PostgreSQL. The new raw query works fine in PostgreSQL Query tool.

```
def home(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        cursor = connection.cursor() 
        # cursor.execute('''select (select Date from datepd where dateid=Datepd_dateid) as Date,
        #                 (select QCL from productioninfo where infoid=Datepd_dateid) as QCL,
        #                 round(AVG(Gap),2) as gap FROM dailyproduction GROUP BY Datepd_dateid ORDER BY Date ASC''')
        cursor.execute('''select (select "Date" from public.surmafloor_datepd where dateid="Datepd_dateid") as "Date",
                        (select "QCL" from public.surmafloor_productioninfo where infoid="Datepd_dateid") as "QCL",
                        round(AVG("Gap"),2) as gap FROM public.surmafloor_dailyproduction GROUP BY "Datepd_dateid" ORDER BY "Date" ASC''')
        avrg = cursor.fetchall()
```

The code still running the previous query.
Right now I am having this error:

```
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\FKL_CIT-02\Envs\mis\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\FKL_CIT-02\Envs\mis\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\FKL_CIT-02\fkl\pdfloor\surmafloor\views.py", line 243, in homeChart
    cursor.execute('''select (select Date from datepd where dateid=Datepd_dateid) as Date,
  File "C:\Users\FKL_CIT-02\Envs\mis\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 98, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\FKL_CIT-02\Envs\mis\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 66, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "C:\Users\FKL_CIT-02\Envs\mis\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 75, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "C:\Users\FKL_CIT-02\Envs\mis\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\FKL_CIT-02\Envs\mis\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "C:\Users\FKL_CIT-02\Envs\mis\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 82, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "dailyproduction" does not exist
LINE 3:                     round(AVG(Gap),2) as gap FROM dailyprodu...
```

Comment: relation "dailyproduction" does not exist -> you do not have dailyproduction table in database

Comment: I had it in my MySQL database. I am not referring 'dailyproduction' table. Have a look again, I commented on the MySQL raw query line where I had dailyproduction table.

Comment: did you restart your server, cleaned pyc files?

Comment: No, which server I need to restart. I did restart my PC but that didn't work.